# Android Studio Component Positioning

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I am creating an android app and I'm facing an issue in layout design.
The current design is as follows:

[image: I want the switch to be at top of the app]

I want the switch to be at the top of this activity. My component tree is as follows:

[image]

I have tried giving the switch margin bottom, but it pushes the buttons downward.

Comment: Share us xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this between **switch4** and **linear layout (layout of buton_0_0)**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem! Do you have any online resource where I can get a better understanding of layouts?

Comment: You are welcome, Look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout  or  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android